# Cost of string comparison in Python3

Tags: python, string, performance, comparison

What exactly is the cost of string comparison in Python? I heard that sometimes it is constant but sometimes it depends on the length of the string.

Comment: It depends on the length of the strings and on the similarity of the strings. If your strings are both a thousand characters long, and they're all the same except for the last character, that's a thousand character comparisons. But if they are different at the first character, that's only one character comparison.

Comment: maybe that helps http://pit-claudel.fr/clement/blog/modeling-and-measuring-string-comparison-performance-in-c-cpp-csharp-and-python/

Comment: It's constant if the lengths differ. Otherwise, it's an O(n) operation.

Comment: [Here's the code for Python3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L10755).  There are a couple of different comparison functions that get called under different circumstances.